# How to run a timer-based app at the same speed when the screensaver is active

Tags: swift, macos, nstimer

I wrote a pseudo real-time simulation MacOS app that uses an NSTimer. I'd like to run the app for hours or possibly days. My problem is the app doesn't run in real-time when the screensaver turns on, the computer goes to sleep, or the monitor is off. When I use an app to prevent the computer/display from going to sleep and a "Hot Corner" to disable the screensaver, the app runs in real-time as expected.

Here are steps to reproduce the issue

1. Create a new MacOS "App" project
2. Replace the fcode in ViewController.swift with the following code
3. Run the app
4. Activate the screensaver or turn off the monitor

---

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var startTime:Date?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var maxValue:TimeInterval = -1e20
        // Create a Timer that fires every second
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            if let delta = self?.startTime?.timeIntervalSinceNow {
                let value = abs(delta)
                if value > maxValue {
                    maxValue = value
                }
                print("delta: \(value) max: \(maxValue)")
            }
            self?.startTime = Date()
        }
        RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
    }
}
```

The closure code should fire once per second. With the screensaver on, the code executes about once every 11 seconds.

From Apple's NSTimer documentation,

> A timer is *not* a real-time mechanism. If a timer’s firing time
> occurs during a long run loop callout or while the run loop is in a
> mode that isn't monitoring the timer, the timer doesn't fire until
> the next time the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual
> time at which a timer fires can be significantly later

Question: Does anyone know how to create a time-based app that fires at the same rate with the screensaver on or the monitor off?

OS: MacOS 10.15.3, SDK: Xcode 11.3

Comment: pmset may lead you to a solution

Comment: @JeffHolt after more debugging, I found that an NSTimer fires inconsistently when the screensaver is running. I suspect pmset won't fix that issue.

Comment: just measure the delay and simulate the required number of steps in your simulation to 'catch up' with real time. it doesn't matter if the display is not up to date when the screensaver is on!

Comment: I agree. You should not be relying on the timer to fire precisely in any case. The only way to know how long has elapsed between firings is to look at the clock. And it looks like you're doing that. Running in the background changes nothing about that.